# Which is best way to apply to a company?

Tags: applications, fresher

I am a fresher and I am trying to get a job. I have applied for several companies like TCS,amazon,hp, etc., Is it better to get a referral of a employee in the company and forward our CV from them or to apply through their respective websites??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I often feel i get call only if we apply through referral.Why is that so?

Consider that for many companies, they get quite a lot of CVs - which they have to go through and weed out the unsuitable ones. This is a point where things like typos, bad grammar and the person looking through ti all come into play - this is where even small things can mean the CV ends up on the rejection pile.

Now, when it comes to referrals - this is someone who has already been hired. They company hired them as they found them to be competent (for the position they were hired), so a recommendation from someone that is known to have good judgement (after all, they wouldn't have hired them if they didn't believe that), carries more weight than a CV.

Comment: Not everybody is gifted to have some referral in their dream company. Is there any chance for a common man to better his chances of getting through

Comment: @Anirudh - work on your CV. Get some public artifacts out there (talking in conferences, blog, community participation and such)

Comment: Make that: a specific referral carries more weight than a random CV :) Referrals matter if those who are tasked with screening resumes just hate what they are doing - I haven't met anyone yet who ever screened resumes and who didn't see it as some form of torture, and I am no exception. Referrals are definitely easier on everyone. Aside from that, a large percentage of resumes contain what can be charitably described as fiction writing, creative wording and fact spinning.

Answer (score 1):

At our company, we work with a recruiter who really understands our team and what we need, so it is a more efficient use of our time to pay attention to the resumes that he brings us than to sort through all of the general resumes that the company receives. I've had the best luck in my job search by making my resume available on the places where the recruiters are searching for candidates for a specific opening, like LinkedIn and other online job search sites.

Comment: Agreed, if you have no inside contacts and no particular special in-demand skills then recruiters are probably the way to go. You just need to ask if they have a pre-existing relationship with any particular company that you are interested in. If they do then that gives you a foot in the door. However, I'm not sure that new-grads are high on recruiters lists because companies can easily find new-grads to interview by simply calling area colleges and informing them of any openings without having to pay recruiter fees.

Comment: @Dunk You're right. I misunderstood the question and thought this was a first job after graduation, not an internship. Fresher isn't a term I hear much on this side of the Atlantic. We wouldn't use a recruiter for that type of role. All my internships were through the university or from family friend referrals. I wasn't picky though, I just wanted practical experience.